# Is iwlwifi or iwldvm or wext the wireless driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers

From https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi:

> iwlwifi is the wireless driver for Intel's current wireless chips.

From https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#firmware

```
Device  Kernels     Module  Firmware
Intel® Wireless WiFi 5150AGN    2.6.29+     iwldvm  iwlwifi-5150-ucode-8.24.2.2.tgz
```

which says `iwldvm` is the "module".

1. Isn't a driver a module?
2. which  is the wireless driver (module) for the wifi adapter,   iwlwifi or iwldvm?
3. Is wext also some kind of driver module, but why is it not listed in `lsmod` or `lshw`? See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198509/674

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Not every module is a driver, and drivers can use multiple modules. For further information read [this U&L thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47208/what-is-the-difference-between-kernel-drivers-and-kernel-modules).

As for your specific question:

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep description
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
$ modinfo iwldvm | grep description
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
$ modinfo iwldvm | grep depends
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
```

As you see, the `iwldvm` module belongs to a driver for a very **specific** group of Intel WiFi chips. It is optimized to work the best with the WiFi Link AGN devices.

However, it says to **depend on** `iwlwifi`, which, on the contrary, simply states to be a "Intel WiFi driver", so it is a **generic** driver, which should work with a lot of Intel WiFi devices.

I don't know the exact way Intel drivers work, but I could imagine the following:

iwlwifi enables basic interaction with the WiFi device. If you only had iwlwifi, your WiFi could work perfectly, reduced or not at all.

For the latter two cases, here comes a more specified module, such as iwldvm, which contains operations needed for more complex tasks. With this driver, the WiFi should work properly, but it still requires iwlwifi.

Comment: Thanks! What about `wext`? Is it also some kind of driver module, but not listed in `lsmod`? See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198509/674